Metaball particle system not showing motion blur (Cycles blender 3.0.0)
I am making a particle system that uses a metaball as a its object instance particle and its working rather nicely. I have enabled motion blur in render properties, however, when I try to render out a single image of the particle system there is no motion blur captured.
I thought well maybe since the metaballs aren't actually mesh they don't capture motion blur in this method. But I added two keyframes of a left to right animation of a single metaball and it does in fact capture motion blur in this method.
It's just not showing up when used in a particle system. I also tried using a UV sphere along with the metaball in a collection with the particle system and the UV spheres capture motion blur but the metaballs will not. Does anyone know why the metaballs are not displaying motion blur while used in a particle system?

Metaball surface calculations have topology changes, making it hard to track changes across frames, making motion blur impossible to calculate as far as I know.
